# Change ImageView background in a Row of ListView

Tags: android, listview, imageview, row

I have a problem that I don't think can be solved.

I would like to change an ImageView background that is inside a row in a ListView. The row is a custom view with two TextView and an ImageView.

I have the ListView id, the number of the row that contains the ImageView i want to edit and the ImageView id, of course.

There is any way to access the right ImageView?

Thanks for any answer.

UPDATE

Better Explanation:
I have a list of device. They are loaded from an adapter, which takes values from an array.
After the list is created, i start a new activity sending an array which contains the devices address.
The other activity receive the array, scan for devices in range (Bluetooth) and get a list of those.
Then I confront the two array and if there is a device in range, I change the image on the ListView relative to that device. The index of the array is the row number in the ListView.

I don't think I need to post any code since the array sending from an activity to the other is made via Intent and that works. Debugging I have bot the array.

I just need a way to access the image in the row of that list.

Comment: your Class code and your adapter would be helpful to let us help you

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.

I'll post here the code if someone, some day will have my problem:

```
// We have the listview, list of online devices and the list of our devices!
        // Init ListView
        ListView device_list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.deviceListView);

        // Loop for all the online devices found
        for (int j = 0; j < mLeDevices.size(); j++){

            // Get the online device address
            BluetoothDevice device = mLeDevices.get(j);
            String deviceAddress = mLeDevices.get(j).getAddress();

            // Loop for all the devices in the ListView
            for (int i = 0; i < device_address.size(); i++) {

                // Compare devices address
                if (device_address.get(i).compareTo(deviceAddress) == 0) {
                    int visiblePosition = device_list.getFirstVisiblePosition();
                    View v = device_list.getChildAt(i - visiblePosition);
                    ImageView state = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.item_state);
                    state.setImageResource(R.drawable.led_on);
                }
            }
        }
```

The list will have no more than 5 elements, so no problems with the list scrolling and losing the index.
I Actually would like to ask a question. Is it right to assume that the position in the ListView starts from 0? Or the first element index is 1?

Answer (score 0):

If i understand your question right then you can use the following idea

If you know the position of the image view then you can try something like this in your getView method

```
imageView.setBackground(R.drawable.normalBackground);
if(position==yourRequiredPosition){
     imageView.setBackground(R.drawable.newBackground);
}
```

this way it will always set normalBackground for imageView in each row, but for the yourRequiredposition row newBackground will be set. Only thing is you have to have a way to figure out "yourRequiredPosition"